# A word describing a skilful footballer

Tags: meaning

Is there a common word describing a footballer who skilfully dribbles the ball and get past defenders easily?

Comment: Here in the US, basketball players dribble.  There's no dribbling in football here.  But there IS dribbling in soccer.

Comment: In what context? Everything is relative... If I go up against a bunch of kids, I'd be considered an extremely good player (in comparison)... Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard phrases used like "fancy footwork" and "dancing through the defense" and "talented player".

fancy footwork - the action of a skilled attacker who moves their feet quickly and in the right way so as to guide the ball around the defense

dancing through the defense - the movement of a skilled attacker who dodges defenders to reach the goal

talented player - a generic description to describe the skill of the player in a positive light.

Basically, there is no single "common word" per say, however analogies are often drawn to liken the movement of the players legs to dancing or moving at speed.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you're looking for superlatives to describe a certain attribute, not a word to actually *define* that attribute.

You could use the adjectives "tricky", "fancy", "agile", etc. to describe "dribbling" but you are unbounded in your search for superlatives about a player.  You can pick any number of suitable words here.

Even if you pick [just one article about Lionel Messi](https://www.theguardian.com/football/blog/2015/may/07/lionel-messi-barcelona-bayern-munich), you will find a wealth of words, similes, metaphors and phrases used to describe his ability.

In short, there isn't one word to describe a good dribbler.  But you can come up with plenty.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right. After detailed research, I haven't found one word to describe such a player.

Answer (score 0):

"A [Stanley Matthews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_Matthews)". But this would only be comprehensible to Brits of a certain age. He was known as "The wizard of dribble".

This style of football has rather gone out of fashion, but I have heard the runs some modern exponents make described as “[mazey](https://www.wordnik.com/words/mazey)”.